# Need to add the button next to the add to cart button

Tags: custom-theme, custom-button

Changed the code in add to cart phtml file but it is not showing changes in the file.[image]

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
**strong text**
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $buttonTitl = __('Add to Cart'); ?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       min="0"
                       value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            <a class="primary action" href="#">hello</a>
  <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitl) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                     disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitl) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Flush cache and check again.

Comment: I guess there is some path issue thats what has been mentioned in many links

Comment: You can check from where the template is called by enabling template path hints.

Comment: I have enabled it but unable to understand it

Comment: 176 679 344 my anydesk id please if you can access and solve it

Comment: Removed whole code from the addtocart.phtml and still no changes, unable to understand the issue

Comment: Sorry I can't help you through anydesk.

Comment: Add your full file path where you added changes.

Comment: no changes found

Comment: /var/www/demo/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
themes path

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="sample.product.button" before="-" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::product/view/sample_button.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="sample.product.button.additional" before="-" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::product/view/sample_button.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/product/view**

**sample_button.phtml**

```
<button>TEST Button</button>
```